# SDL SetWindowDisplayMode on 1920 x 1080

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2

I have a program built with sdl2 and c++ and when while it runs I want to change the resolution in 1920 x 1080 if is supported.

I make the tests with a TV and it outputs fine when my desktop is set to 1920x1080.

But when is set to less resolution I try this:

```
int WIDTH = 1920;
int HEIGHT = 1080;

auto sdlWindow = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow(
        "My Window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        WIDTH, HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN),
        SDL_DestroyWindow
);

SDL_DisplayMode dm = { SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UNKNOWN,0, 0,0,0 };
dm.w=WIDTH; dm.h=HEIGHT;

SDL_SetWindowDisplayMode(sdlWindow.get(), &dm);
```

The resolution changes but the window is not shown completely, leaving black space in the right and down of the screen, like the window can render until its previous desktop resolution

Comment: I work on ubuntu 16.04, the values are 1920 and 1080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work, I had to change the window creation call like that

```
auto sdlWindow = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow(
    "My Window",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    20, 20,
    SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL),
    SDL_DestroyWindow
);
```

In this call I shouldn't set the width and height bigger from the actual screen size (else SDL_SetWindowDisplayMode wont work) so I use small numbers.

this code can be rewritten without small pointer like that:

```
SDL_Window* sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "My Window",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    20, 20,
    SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

...

SDL_DestroyWindow(sdlWindow);
```